# Get the proportion of events by group, given the condition of another column

Tags: r

I'd like to know the proportion of events by site (i.e., by group) where "y" occurred at least once.

Example of data:

```
site event occurrence 
A    A01   y          
A    A01   n          
A    A02   n          
A    A02   n          
A    A03   y          
B    B01   y          
B    B01   n          
B    B02   n          
B    B02   n
```

Desired outcome:

```
site event occurrence proporition
A    A01   y          0.666
A    A01   n          0.666
A    A02   n          0.333
A    A02   n          0.333
A    A03   y          0.666
B    B01   y          0.5
B    B01   n          0.5
B    B02   n          0.5
B    B02   n          0.5
```

So, at site "A", a the proportion of unique events with at least one occurrence of "Y" was 0.666.
At site "B", a the proportion of unique events with at least one occurrence of "Y" was 0.5.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, proporition:= uniqueN(event[occurrence == 'y'])/uniqueN(event), site]
df

#   site event occurrence proporition
#1:    A   A01          y   0.6666667
#2:    A   A01          n   0.6666667
#3:    A   A02          n   0.6666667
#4:    A   A02          n   0.6666667
#5:    A   A03          y   0.6666667
#6:    B   B01          y   0.5000000
#7:    B   B01          n   0.5000000
#8:    B   B02          n   0.5000000
#9:    B   B02          n   0.5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    group_by(site) %>%
    mutate(props = n_distinct(event[occurrence == "y"])/n_distinct(event))
```

Comment: Can you give explanation of your code in order to help your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Split-Apply-Combine Base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df, split(df, site)),
    function(x) {
     n <- length(unique(x$event))
     occurences <- sum(ifelse(x$occurrence == "y", 1, 0))
     x$proporition <- 
       ifelse(x$occurrence == "y", (occurences / n), 1 - (occurences / n))
     x
    }
  )
)
```